# Redmine: want to run webrick service as background process

Tags: ubuntu, redmine, webrick

I am completely done with my redmine installation in ubuntu server. I am testing the server using the following command:

```
ruby script/server webrick -e production
```

But when I press ctrl+z it stops. So I want to start this one as a service or process in Ubuntu.

I tried this with this one:

```
ruby script/server webrick -e production -du
```

It shows the process is running but in the browser no page is shown.

Do you have any suggestion how I can resolved the problem??

Comment: Not an answer, but you're not really supposed to run it with webrick apart from for testing purposes.

Comment: Ctrl+z _does_ stop things - it sends the suspend interrupt.  Type `bg` to resume the last program you suspended in the background.

Answer (score 2):

The following command works well on my system :

```
./script/server webrick -e development -d
```

The server is not stopped when I close my shell.